# эта программа раскладывает число на простые множители но не работает с простыми числами , как избежать этой ошибки

Tags: java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File("output.txt"));
        int n = in.nextInt();
        String str = "";
        int k = 0;
        int a = 0;
        boolean fl = false;
        for (int j = 2; j <= Math.sqrt(n); j++) {
            if (n != 1) {
                while (n % j == 0) {
                    n /= j;
                    k++;
                    a++;
                }
                if (!(n % j == 0) && a != 0) {
                    str += j + "";
                    if (k > 1) {
                        str += "^" + k + "*";
                    } else {
                        str += "*";
                    }
                }
                k = 0;
                a = 0;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (n != 1) {
            System.out.println(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1) + "*" + n);
        } else {
            System.out.println(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1));
        }
    }    
}
```

Ошибка:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Comment: Это не ресурс, где за вас кто-то что-то будет доделывать. Пробуйте сделать сами, приводите примеры кода и задавайте вопросы - тогда вам, возможно, помогут.

Comment: ну как можно избежать ошибки когда даются простые числа?

Comment: @Айнур а вы текст ошибки (exception-a) видели? Понимаете, почему она появляется?

Comment: он выходит за пределы строки потому чтоа строку str ничего не добавляетсяпосле прогона

Answer (score 1):

Текст ошибки вам обо всем говорит:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

В случае с простыми числами переменная `str` будет пустой. Нужно добавить соответствующую проверку проверку перед `if (n != 1) {`:

```
if (!str.isEmpty()) {
    if (n != 1) {
        System.out.println(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1) + "*" + n);
    } else {
        System.out.println(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1));
    }
} else {
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

**PS:** вам нужно привести код в порядок: все ресурсы (`Scanner`) в конце должны быть закрыты (а `PrintWriter` у вас вообще не используется) - советую использовать конструкцию [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: На мой взгляд, конструкция `if - else if - else` здесь будет выглядеть лучше, так как это 3 абсолютно разных случаях и группировать их не стоит. Но это, конечно, дело субъективное.